# AtTiny44 and AtTiny 85 communication

Tags: serial, i2c, softwareserial, attiny, attiny85

I'm working on a project where I use two microcontrollers: an AtTiny44 (20MHz ext clock) and an AtTiny85 (8MHz internal).

What I'm trying to achieve is an I2C communication between the 85 and the 44, with the 44 acting as master and the 85 as slave, then transmit the data read from both of them to a PC with FDTI cable using softwareSerial.

I started with writing the AtTiny85 code:

```
   #include <TinyWireS.h>
   #define ADC3 A3

   void setup() {
      TinyWireS.begin(I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS); // join i2c network
      TinyWireS.onRequest(requestEvent);
      pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
      pinMode(ADC3,INPUT_PULLUP);
   }

   void loop() {
      // This needs to be here
      TinyWireS_stop_check();
   }

   // Gets called when the ATtiny receives an i2c request
   void requestEvent() {
     int val=analogRead(ADC3);
     byte valLow = val & 0xff;
     byte valHigh = (val >> 8);
     TinyWireS.send(valHigh);
     TinyWireS.send(valLow);
   }
```

With this I am able to send the data read from an adc (A3 pin) to an Arduino as 2 bytes

The Arduino code:

```
  #include <Wire.h>

  int check=0;

  void setup() {
     Wire.begin();        // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
     Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial for output
  }

  void loop() {
      Wire.requestFrom(8, 2);    // request 2 bytes from slave device #8

      while (Wire.available()&&check<2) { // slave may send less than 
                                          // requested
        int c = Wire.read(); // receive a byte as int
        check++;
        int d = Wire.read();
        check++;
        int number = d | c << 8; //convert two bytes as int
        Serial.println(number);  
     }
     check=0;
     delay(500);
   }
```

Maybe the `check` variable is useless, but it's not a problem, because I'm getting the right reading on serial monitor.

I then moved to the AtTiny44; I have an onboard thermistor, and I need to print on softwareSerial the value read from this and the value read from the AtTiny85 board.

This is the code, using TinyWireM:

```
  #include <TinyWireM.h>
  #include <USI_TWI_Master.h>
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

  SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1); // RX, TX

  int adc = 2;
  int check=0;

  void setup() {
    pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(0, INPUT);
    pinMode(4,INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(6,INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(adc, INPUT);
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    TinyWireM.begin();        // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
    while (!mySerial) {
      ;
    }
    mySerial.println("Serial comm started");
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
 }

 void loop() {
   mySerial.println((int)analogRead(adc));
   TinyWireM.requestFrom(8, 2);    // request 2 bytes from slave device #8
   while (TinyWireM.available()&&check<2) { // slave may send less than    
                                            // requested
   digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
   int c = TinyWireM.receive(); // receive a byte as character
   check++;
   int d = TinyWireM.receive();
   check++;
   int number = d | c << 8;
   mySerial.println(number);  
   }
 check=0;
 delay(500);
 }
```

The softwareSerial is working good (I get to write the ADC data from the 44) but I can't find where the problem on I2C is (on console monitor `mySerial.println(number)` sends out 0).

What I excluded so far: connections error, clock skew (the clocks are distant between them), pull-up on I2c bus (they are high in both devices)

Comment: Why use I2C? Maybe other protocols could be faster/simpler/less pins for this use?

Comment: I don't think there are simpler protocol, or with less pin. I thought of using two softwareSerial but they can't work togheter at the same time

Comment: You data rate seems pretty low, and maybe you only need to send in one direction over the link between the two units? If so, maybe just a single signal wire and a ground between them. Sender drives the wire high for 1ms to signal a "0", 2ms to signal a "1". Really simple bit banged serial port.

Comment: I need to send data in only one way, yes. I'd like to use I2C, but I'm interested in your workaround. Can you point me to some hints? Also how can I manage the master requesting data to the slave in your solution?

Comment: Do you need to have the master request? Why not just have the slave always blindly sending?

Comment: It could also blindly send, but how I can manage the timings between the softwareSerial and the bit banged serial?

Comment: On the chip connected to the FDTI, make a pin change ISR for the piun that is connected to the data line coming from the remote. Everytime the pin changes low-to-high, save the current time. Everytime it changes high-to-low, look at the diff between current time and saved time. If time is ~1 second then received a 0 bit, if time is ~2 seconds then received a 1 bit. shift them into a holding variable until you have a byte of data. When you get it working, you can make much faster, but with 1 & 2 seconds easy to debug with an LED.

Comment: Perhaps the ATtiny85 can't handle the I2C clock rate being generated by the AtTiny44.  Try running them both at the same clock speed.

Answer (score -1):

> the 85 as slave

writing a slave, especially an i2c slave, isn't for the faint of heart. typically you use a state machine to help handle that.

one great example is the one presented by nxp in old LPC210x datasheet. AVRs share the same i2c hardware so it is immensely portable to the avr.

Comment: I know that, but the funny thing is that is the attiny44 master that is not working!